# How to plot the frequency of a specific word through time

Tags: python, regex, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset

```
Column1      Column2                                Column3   ....
2020/05/02   She heard the gurgling water          (not relevant)
2020/05/02   The water felt delightful
2020/05/03   Another instant and I shall never again see the sun, this water, that gorge!
2020/05/04   Fire would have been her choice.
2020/05/04   Everywhere you go in world are water fountains.
...
2020/05/31   She spelled "mother" several times.
```

I would like to plot the frequency of word 'water' through time. How could I do?

What I have tried is defining a pattern:

```
pattern=['water']
```

and apply `re.search`:

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern,x).group(1))
```

to select the word `water` in `Column2`. 
To group by date and count them, I would use

```
df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])['Column1'].agg({'Frequency':'count'})
```

and to plot them I would use matplotlib (using a bar plot):

```
df['Column1'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

This is what I have tried, with a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in string.count(substring) method for strings in Python. Then count and sum the frequency column by each day of the dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['2020/05/02','2020/05/02','2020/05/03','2020/05/04','2020/05/04'],
    'Column2':["She heard the gurgling water", "The water felt delightful",
    "Another instant and I shall never again see the sun, this water, that gorge!",
    "Fire would have been her choice.",
    "Everywhere you go in world are water fountains"]})
# lazy way to convert strings to dates
df['Column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column1'], infer_datetime_format=True)

pattern = "water"

df['Frequency'] = df['Column2'].apply(lambda x: x.count(pattern))

# sum the frequency of the word 'water' over each separate day
ax = df['Frequency'].groupby(df['Column1'].dt.to_period('D')).sum().plot(kind='bar')

# force integer yaxis labels
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=6)

# Rotate tick marks on x-axis
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Column1": ["2020/05/02", "2020/05/02", "2020/05/03", "2020/05/04", "2020/05/04", "2020/05/31"],
    "Column2": ["She heard the gurgling water water", "The water felt delightful", "Another instant and I shall never again see the sun, this water, that gorge!", "Fire would have been her choice.", "Everywhere you go in world are water fountains.", "She spelled 'mother' several times."]
})
```

**Logic**

```
# for each string, get the number of times a phrase appears
df['phrase_count'] = df['Column2'].str.count('water')

# plot the results
df.groupby('Column1')['phrase_count'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

chain df.`assign` and `str.count` to extract word count. `groupby` `column1` and plot either `.plot,bar()` or `.plot(kind='bar')`

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


(df.assign(count=df.column2.str.count('water'))).groupby('column1')['count'].sum().plot.bar()
#(df.assign(count=df.column2.str.count('water'))).groupby('column1')['count'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
        plt.ylabel('Count')
        plt.xlabel('Date')
```

Plot

[image]